# slider to control an LED

Tags: arduino

I have been enjoying working with appinventer.I controlled my home appliances with my app and now working to control the led intensity or a motor speed with the same.

I made it but what it resulted is that I cant get what I communicate through slider thumb position -----on arduino serial monitor instead it shows other(but between 0-255)

this is my code-----

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
int led1 =11;
int c;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(9,10);
void setup()
{
    pinMode(led1,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(1200);
    mySerial.begin(57600);
    Serial.println("bluetooth controlled home appliances");
}
void loop()
{ 
    if (mySerial.available())
    {
        c=mySerial.read();
        Serial.print("value received is :     ");
        Serial.println(c);
        int p=map(c,0,255,0,255);
        Serial.print("value mapped is :    ");
        Serial.println(p);   
        analogWrite(led1,p);
    } else {
        Serial.println("no available data found");
    }

}
```

Comment: You tag Android, but post Arduino. This doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

To control the led intensity you should use a pwm pin and write the number received. You cant wok with the analogwrite.